# application screen sizing differenciations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I just uploaded my app to the app store, and tried downloading it on an iPhone XR and SE. Each of the screens of the devices seem to be messed up dimensions. However when I go into xCode  and change device size manually in the storyboard to whatever iPhone it is, its looks fine on the device when its run. I don't get why it doesn't automatically adjust to the screen size. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Storyboard is a preview, not a completely accurate representation. The only way to know for sure is to build the app to simulators/devices of the sizes you're looking for. If layouts are wonky, then I would suggest looking at your build output for constraints breaking.